# How to redirect from a subdomain to a subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I need help redirecting a subdomain to a subfolder on my website using the .htaccess file. I am not a pro in regards to configuring the .htaccess file, so please forgive me if my problem is a simple fix.

In my .htaccess file, I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [R=301]
```

It almost works, but when I enter **subdomain.domain.com** into the address bar, I get redirected to **subdomain.domain.com/subfolder/**

This is really close, but I don't want the preceding subdomain in the redirected URL, I want the redirection to go to **domain.com/subfolder/**

Answer (score 14):

You need to change your RewriteRule to include the new domain you're trying to redirect too, otherwise it will treat the beginning `/` as a new path on the current domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301]
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You may write in the following way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/subfolder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/subfolder/$1 [L,R]
```