# How can I check the requested url before it being redirected on webserver

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I want to redirect a subdomain to a subfolder on my server. I set the A-Record on my DNS Server for blog.domain.com to go to my main server www.domain.com.
Using the following htaccess (ubuntu server) - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481005/how-to-redirect-from-a-subdomain-to-a-subfolder-using-htaccess):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

Sadly - it's not working.
So I've checked apache's access.log and saw, that the first request the web server received was already www.domain.com and not blog.domain.com.

How can I find out the Request-List to check where the requests got wrong?

Comment: You have access to VHost config, or server config itself?

Comment: @hjpotter92 yes. Can you point me where I have to look ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to specify `ServerAlias` directive.

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks it helps.

Comment: I found that there a permanent "Redirect Directive" in the vhost setting (forget to check this-my bad). After deleting this and adding ServerName and ServerAlias, it works. Thanks @hjpotter92