# Wildcard subdomain doesn't include subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel

In cPanel (at subdomain management) I've set up a wildcard like to following:

`*.example.com` > `public_html/subDomainHandler`

Every (non existent subdomain) request like `abc.example.com` redirects properly to `example.com/subDomainHandler`.

But requests like `abc.example.com/subfolder` doesn't redirect to `example.com/subDomainHandler`.

I am not at my best in regular expressions, but can anybody give me a RewriteCondition for `.htaccess`?

Comment: are these rules being written to an .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes they may be written in htaccess.

Comment: There should be no "redirect" here; do you mean "resolve"? Or have you specifically set up a subdomain "redirect" in cPanel? A request like `abc.example.com/subfolder` should _resolve_ to `example.com/subDomainHandler/subfolder` without having to do anything extra? Where is it resolving (or "redirecting"?) to?

Comment: It shoud resolve. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

### Htaccess Rewrite Rule - Try1

I think your answer could be modeled on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481076/1688441 .

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com\(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subDomainHandler/$1 [R=301]
```

### Try2

Another option:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/subDomainHandler%1 [R=301,L]
```

From: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13475/redirect-rewrite-subdomain-to-subfolder

Comment: So, when setting up a wildcard domain, make sure also to install the SSL for that (wildcard) domain. Sometime's 'old-school-thinking' includes a (little) gap.

Comment: No. But I will test it on another server soon. As I said, the missing SSL is proberbly blocking the (correct?) result of the regular expression..